# How would this query work in SQL Server (from access)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

I just recently converted us from straight Access database to Access front end and SQL Server backend with linked table. We are coming from Access 2007 and to SQL Server 17 (currently Express, but Standard shortly).

I have some "Select Query (Replicated)" queries that we were using in Access that I want to convert to pass through queries in the new linked Access front end.

However, I'm not sure why it doesn't work aleady. This is the SQL View in Access (the table name was `ADDRESSES`)

```
SELECT ADDRESSES.STEXT,
       ADDRESSES.COMPANY,
       ADDRESSES.ADDRESS,
       ADDRESSES.CITY,
       ADDRESSES.STATE,
       ADDRESSES.[MAIL-DATE],
       ADDRESSES.ORDER,
       ADDRESSES.[IN-DATE],
       ADDRESSES.[CHK-DATE],
       ADDRESSES.VERIFIER,
       ADDRESSES.DNC
FROM ADDRESSES
WHERE(((ADDRESSES.STEXT) Like "schlawoffice*"));
```

Now, in SQL the table name is `dbo.MSTR-SENT` rather than `ADDRESSES`. How would I make this SQL Server compliant for the new pass through query? Simply changing the table name?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you try it?  What happen if you change `ADDRESSES` to `dbo.MSTR-SENT`?  Have you tried it?

Comment: Also the syntax for LIKE is: Like 'schlawoffice%', see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I did try it, and you're right about the syntax that was an oversight.

Comment: Totally off-topic, but there's no such thing as "SQL Server 17". The release that's packaged as SQL Server 2017 is SQL Server version 14. In 1998, Microsoft released the last numbered version, SQL Server 7. Thereafter, they started naming the releases with the year they came out, so SQL Server version 8 is known as SQL Server 2000. Crazy? Yes. But in SSMS you can see the numeric version right after the server name in the Object Explorer. Here's the unofficial official [build list](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Well, that's still really interesting! As long as there is correlation I guess it doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get in the habit of using aliases. It can make a wall of text into something that is easy to read. Also you should avoid using reserved words as column or oject names. And last but not least I would suggest not using special characters in table names. Stick to alphabetic characters (and only numbers if you absolutely have to use it which should be almost never).

Your query in sql server would look like this.

```
SELECT s.STEXT
    , s.COMPANY
    , s.[ADDRESS]
    , s.CITY
    , s.[STATE]
    , s.[MAIL-DATE]
    , s.[ORDER]
    , s.[IN-DATE]
    , s.[CHK-DATE]
    , s.VERIFIER
    , s.DNC 
FROM dbo.[MSTR-SENT] s 
WHERE s.STEXT Like 'schlawoffice%'
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand. I was not really familiar with aliases, that's really interesting. I'll have to read more on that. In the original Access query, the dataset is editable and a new line can be added, though in the pass-through query the recordset is unedtiable. I'm guesing I would have to take a different approach?

Comment: Yes you would need to issue an update statement to update the data.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have been a big help